# cin to function arguments without variable

Tags: c++, c++11, input

I want to pass user input directly to function without variable. Now I am doing this:

```
int temp, len;
cin >> len;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    cin >> temp;
    foo(temp);
}
```

Can I do it without temp? Maybe I should not use "cin"?

Comment: why do you want that?...

Comment: Idk. Think just thought about that :)

Comment: The C++ I/O library depends on the type of the argument to `operator>>` to know what kind of thing to read. `opeator>>` is defined in terms of the current locale's `num_get` facet's `get` member function, but that member function also depends on the type of an argument to select an appropriate overload which reads the desired type. With a simple function as you propose, how would the return type be identified? Multiple functions with different names would not conform to the philosophy of the C++ library.

Comment: Of course, you could write your own function to wrap around the temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still create wrapper function:

```
template <typename T>
T get_input(std::istream& cin)
{
    T res;
    std::cin >> res;
    return res;
}
```

And then:

```
const int len = get_input<int>(std::cin);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    foo(get_input<int>(std::cin));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

No. This is not possible. What you could do is put the input function inside `foo()`, so for example:

```cpp
int foo(bar = null) { // initializing the variable makes it optional
    int temp;
    if (bar == null) {
        std::cin >> temp;
    }
    else {
        temp = bar;
    }

    // put whatever code here

    return temp;
}

int main() {
    int bar = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

However, it is not possible to pass the result of an input statement directly to a function in C++.

Comment: I want "foo" argument was an integer to use in other parts of program

Comment: There you go. Simple revision.

Comment: Oh, I think you don’t understand me I just want to pass to function foo an integer, to use it in that "foo(6)" way too

Comment: I don't understand. `foo(foo())`?

Comment: In start of program foo(<user input>) in other places foo(5)

Comment: I'm assuming this should help you now. If `bar` is `null`, then it was assigned the default value, meaning it was not given. Therefore, we will get the input of the user. If `bar` isn't null, meaning `bar` was given a value, then you assign `temp` the value of `bar`.

Comment: Don't write hard to read code. If you really want to read from `cin` when no argument is passed, then use overloading: `int foo() { int temp; std::cin >> temp; return foo(temp); }`